# Mongo Express doesn't correctly display embedded documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using [Mongo Express](http://andzdroid.github.com/mongo-express/) to view my data in my MongoDB instance during development. I also use the connect-mongo module to store my sessions in MongoDB. For some reason, Mongo Express has difficulties parsing embedded documents created by connect-mongo. The indention doesn't quite work and quotes are escaped. Documents created in connect-mongo do work, as well as those created with mongoose.

[image]

Comment: This is not a programming question. Please discuss or create an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/andzdroid/mongo-express

Comment: @YvesM. Maybe you should check the date on the question first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like connect-mongo stores its data as strings, rather than as embedded documents. You can try using the default MongoDB shell - mongo and confirm if it's the case.